# r reshape2 melt returns Warning in if (drop.margins) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

I have a piece of code that returns a warning message:

```
Warning in if (drop.margins) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

from deep inside the `reshape2` `melt` function as shown in the error message.

How do I correct?

The code is difficult to subset so I've included a description of the data frame. I'm just looking for a hint.

```
S_Melted <- melt(S_Flattened, S_Flattened$db_date)
```

BTW: S_Flattened was created by a cast in an earlier statement:

```
S_Flattened = cast(S, db_date ~ MetricType, value="AvgValue")
```

[image: Here's the description of the S_Flattened data frame]

Comment: It's difficult to give hints without a reproducible example including sample data. A screenshot of your `data.frame` is generally not useful. Can you make your problem reproducible and minimal?

Comment: @MauritsEvers, difficult, but not impossible :-)

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I tip my hat to you;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. You're actually using the "reshape" package, not "reshape2".
2. You're specifying a vector of values as the "id" variable, hence this warning.

Consider the following:

```
long <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("V1", "V2"), class = "factor"), value = 1:6), 
    .Names = c("ID", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using `cast` from "reshape" gives you something that looks like a `data.frame`, but which has a bunch of other attributes.

```
reshape_df <- reshape::cast(long, ID ~ variable)
str(reshape_df)
# List of 3
#  $ ID: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
#  $ V1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
#  $ V2: int [1:3] 4 5 6
#  - attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:3] 1 2 3
#  - attr(*, "idvars")= chr "ID"
#  - attr(*, "rdimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ :'data.frame':  3 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ ID: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
#   ..$ :'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   .. ..$ variable: Factor w/ 2 levels "V1","V2": 1 2
```

Here's your `warning`:

```
reshape::melt(reshape_df, reshape_df$ID)
#      ID value variable
# V1    A     1       V1
# V1.1  B     2       V1
# V1.2  C     3       V1
# V2    A     4       V2
# V2.1  B     5       V2
# V2.2  C     6       V2
# Warning message:
# In if (drop.margins) { :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And the same thing, without a `warning`.

```
reshape::melt(reshape_df, id = "ID")
#      ID value variable
# V1    A     1       V1
# V1.1  B     2       V1
# V1.2  C     3       V1
# V2    A     4       V2
# V2.1  B     5       V2
# V2.2  C     6       V2
```

---

A better approach would be to stop using "reshape" and start using "reshape2", "data.table" (which provides more flexible implementations of `melt` and `dcast` than "reshape2" does), or "tidyr".

Here's the same set of steps with "reshape2":

```
reshape2_df <- reshape2::dcast(long, ID ~ variable)
```

You get back a standard `data.frame` with no extra attributes.

```
str(reshape2_df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ ID: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
#  $ V1: int  1 2 3
#  $ V2: int  4 5 6
```

`melt`ing is not a problem either -- just don't supply it with a vector, as you did in your attempt.

```
reshape2::melt(reshape2_df, "ID")
#   ID variable value
# 1  A       V1     1
# 2  B       V1     2
# 3  C       V1     3
# 4  A       V2     4
# 5  B       V2     5
# 6  C       V2     6
```

Comment: My compliments to you on your prompt and thorough response.  It was of great help. I've discovered that dcast has an oddness.  When I leave the parameter "value = 'AvgValue'" in to identify the column to be summarized in it returns "Using MaxValue as value column: use value.var to override."  When I attempt to use value.var="AvgValue" it seems to work find except when you sue the subset parameter on the call to dcast.  It then can't find the named value.var.

Comment: @PaulBrewster, I'm not sure I follow what oddness you're referring to in your comment. It sounds like a different question or problem entirely. If this answer solved your existing problem, do consider accepting it. You can post your other problem as a new question if needed.